# TypeScript Type Inference Issue with Object Properties in Functional Definitions

Tags: typescript

I'm encountering some type inference problems in Typescript while defining functional objects. Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
type TFn<I extends object, R> = {
    input: I,
    func: (input: I) => R
}

type TObj<T extends { [key: string]: [object, any] }> = { [K in keyof T]: TFn<T[K][0], T[K][1]> }

function def<T extends { [key: string]: [object, any] }>(formObject: TObj<T>) {
    return formObject;
}

const res = def({
    fnc1: {
        input: {hel: 0},
        func: (d) => {
            d.hel // throws: property hel does not exist on type object
            return '';
        },
    },
});

const re = res.fnc1.func({}); // re: any, but it should be string
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgYgOwDwEkoQB7AggJgZygHsAjAKwgGNgAaKAJQD4oBeKAbwCgoeoBLBGACuwAFxQUNbrwBmQhJXEAKAcLESAlK2b1OAX06dQkWAHlySGOiw4CHKAG0A1hBDj8wAE4CA5gF1xB1IKajoAQwQQPyg9ZjZ2RwBpfgQoFxAiGVgA2ERLB0S-BwAGPzoYAqKARj9mA045BWA%20IlTcCBlLa2w8QgTnV3cvXxyg8ipaKAiomMYlGSJPAFtzEPUYVctGLS5eKE8IYCFPVIXl1YmAbn1DSlaPfYhCNnaZJV3ZBSrxD72eVREPwAFhAADbiYp6KR-WTyRRQJS4LQsZi-GG8XAAOhBoKgAHo8VAwJ4iJBPKAoDioLgiE8oAgiMBrHwHq0oMZoMEJtJ0bwDkcTlAAORC668qE8mJSPQaa6cO4IB4HViPfCYmRfdVw94yy74wkHcTTOgkET8Jn4IFEISg3BQEjQDzeBA%20ThAA)

If I replace the [object, any] with object and make it simple void return, it is working for the input parts. here is the link: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgYgOwDwEkoQB7AggJgZygHsAjAKwgGNgA%20KAXigG8AoKdqASwTAFdgAXFBQAaNhwBmvBJSEAKbn0HCAlAzoA3Ip1wsAvixahIsAPLkkMdFhwFmUANoBrCCCH5gAJ24BzALpCpBTUUHp0jEyOANJcCFAuIEQSsAGwiJYOUX50BixSMsCcRHG4EBKW1th4hJHOru5evqlBVMChNHISRJ4AtubByjD9ljRqrBxQnhDAvJ5xXb39rQDc%20oaUxR6TEISMpRJy45IyAIxCRxPsivznABYQADZCAAx6YpeS0rJQcrhq9HQLh8OLgAHT3B5QAD0UKgAHduk5fFB7lNxMCOFMZnMoAByXGrDFvdGhMR6FSrFgbBBbKYMbb4UESU5Mr6HCFCE7k5bQ2FTIRaHQiKAkfhcNr4W5EXgPXAi6AebwIHwsIA)

Answer (score 1):

That inference doesn't work because typescript has no way to obviously map the properties back to the generic type. By packing your input and return value into an array type that has absolutely nothing to do with your actual data's shape/type/structure it can't infer what type you want.

One solution is to just use a generic that is shaped like the data you want:

```
type TFn<I extends object, R> = {
    input: I,
    func: (input: I) => R
}

function def<T extends Record<string, TFn<object,unknown>>>(formObject: T) {
    return formObject;
}

const res = def({
    fnc1: {
        input: {hel: 0},
        func: (d) => {
            d.hel // this is still an error
            return '';
        },
    },
});

const re: string = res.fnc1.func({}); // this works now
```

([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgYgOwDwEkoQB7AggJgZygHsAjAKwgGNgAaKAJQD4oBeKAbwCgoeoBLBGACuwAFxQUNbrwBmQhJXEAKAcLESAlK2b1OAX06c5C4HyIIouCDKQx0WHAQZUiAJ1xJ8wVwIDmdeGRSCmoaeQBrBCIAdwRGeKUZNwBbAHlyKnUYLS5eKFcIYCFXCyTXNIzqAG59Q0pzL3yIQjYrGSVc2QUARnFOvJ5VET6ACwgAG3EABj0pAdl5RSglXC0WZn753lwAOjHxqAB6Q6hgEb5CC6gvPnGDgEMLCFdXN2kt3gKikqgAcl+ah9Zu8oMC9Boapx6ghGgVxF4fAhfKwmvgdjIeujFh1wVUjiczldom5woQotFOEA)) This will be able to partially infer the type, however because we just need something that extends the `TFn` it doesn't properly handle covariance (the thing that ensures that the `input` field and the argument to `func` are the same type) so it still can't give full help to you there.

After a bit of playing with it I'm not sure how to get the behaviour you want although it is likely possible. That said, I'm not clear on how this data structure is likely to be used since if you intent `res.fnc1.func({})` to be a valid call without specifying `hel` field then it is possible I am misunderstanding what exactly you actually want.